# how to use the link with aframe without exit by vr mode?

Tags: hyperlink, aframe

I'm trying to use a-frame link on android smartphone with VR mode. When I start in VR mode if i move the cursor on the link it switch on the new page but exit by VR mode. Is this a way to remain in VR mode when I move to another page?

Answer (score 1):

At the time of wrtitting this answer Firefox Desktop is the only browser that supports in VR navigation

Answer (score 1):

according to the [documentation](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/components/link.html#sidebar), the browser needs to implement the `vrdisplayactivate` event to allow you to switch pages and maintain in VR mode.

I can't find any info about samsung internet, or carmel having this implemented.

Moreover the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/vrdisplayactivate) states, that this is experimental, so i wouldn't be surprised if only Firefox had this functionality.

---

As a workaround, You can try switching scenes, or switching visibility on entire areas, instead of making links.

**UPDATE**

Doug Reeder claims samsung internet (5.6) should also be supporting `vrdisplayactivate`

Comment: Oculus Carmel for Gear VR implements this, too. If you can wait, eventually all browsers should implement vrdisplayactivate. If you need it work everywhere now, intercept the event and swap entities.

Comment: Thank you but I tried this code but not works

 AFRAME.registerComponent('auto-enter-vr', {
           init: function () {
            this.el.sceneEl.enterVR();
           }
          });

....
        <a-scene auto-enter-vr>
....

Comment: @DougReeder can i get a link, I'll throw it in the anwser. I really must be going blind :)

Comment: I don't know of any official documentation, but in practice it works (when it doesn't crash the browser). There's reference to intent to implement it 9 months ago here: https://github.com/facebook/react-vr/issues/176

Comment: Now (as of version 5.6) Samsung Internet for Gear VR supports vrdisplayactivate.

Comment: Niki, your auto-enter-vr component does not work, because a user gesture (for example, tapping on the goggle button) is required to enter VR.

Traversing a link is a special case, that each browser must implement separately.